# Using functions within React Native StyleSheet with Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

Often times I want to do something like

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  square: (size: number) => ({
    width: size,
    height: size,
  }),
})
```

Now this doesn't work, because I get `Type '(size: number) => { width: number; height: number; }' is not assignable to type 'ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle'`. I've tried doing things like

```js
interface Style {
  square: (width: number) => ViewStyle
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create<Style>({
  square: (size: number) => ({
    width: size,
    height: size,
  }),
})
```

But then I get `Type 'Style' does not satisfy the constraint 'NamedStyles<any> | NamedStyles<Style>'.`

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

StylesSheet doesn't support using fuctions but you can use an Object or a Function instead and type the return value with one of these types **ViewStyle** | **TextStyle** | **ImageStyle**

E.g

```
const styles = {
    square: (size: number): ViewStyle => ({
        width: size,
        height: size,
    })
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't support", in terms of working, it works fine, and I actually tried the above solution but it was giving the same error. So do you mean ts doesn't allow it or are there any more issues with functions in styles?

Answer (score 0):

Even if this works fine in JS, as `Stylesheet.create` simply returns the object passed as a parameter, it throws a typing error in TS. The method is typed as followed:

```
export namespace StyleSheet {
  type NamedStyles<T> = {[P in keyof T]: ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle};

  /**
   * Creates a StyleSheet style reference from the given object.
   */
  export function create<T extends NamedStyles<T> | NamedStyles<any>>(
    styles: T | NamedStyles<T>,
  ): T;
}
```

Here you can see that it takes an object as a parameter where each value must be of type `ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle`.
As mentioned by @DanielGabor you can still create a style object without using `Stylesheet.create` where keys return functions that themselves return `ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle`

Answer (score -1):

I don't think StyleSheet supports having functions in it's keys. It is meant to act something like stylesheets from the web. I suspect that what you were doing before was unsupported but now that you're using TypeScript, it's enforcing this.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html